# Start New Remote X Session In Separate TTY

Tags: ssh, multiple-monitors, xorg, tty

In my home setup, I have two computers on the same local network, both run Ubuntu 20.04. I'm hoping to set up a way to access my secondary computer via my primary, by switching to a new TTY, and starting a remote X session. I don't want to share the screen, or access an existing X session. Additionally, the computer I am using to start the remote X session has two monitors, and I would like to take advantage of both.

I have tried a couple of options. I seems like XDMCP could do what I want, but I have had little luck so far (getting access, but only a black screen with cursor). Additionally it seems like it both uses a high bandwidth and is insecure, so ideally I would use something else.

I have tried X2Go, but I have not been able to find a way to start it in a separate TTY, or to have it take advantage of both of my monitors.

I have heard also of things like xvnc, and NoMachine, but I'm not sure if either of those can be run the way I would like.

Is there any existing ways to do this? Or alternatively, any way to compress and/or secure XDMCP? I have seen it may be possible to have XDMCP go over SSH, is this true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

X window sessions don't work the way that you're expecting them to work. You're thinking that there is a "server" on the other side that you're connecting to, and that you want to control.

In reality, it works the opposite. The machine that you're connecting *from* acts as the server, and when you connect, you tell it to display on a different machine.

So, X needs to be running on the machine that you're connecting FROM, then do the following:

- Open an xterm, or whatever your favorite terminal window app is.
- On the local machine, in the terminal, allow connections from the remote host:

  xhost + 192.168.1.2
  (where 192.168.1.2 is the machine you are connecting *to*)
- In the same terminal, open a shell to the remote machine (192.168.1.2), using ssh, with X11 forwarding:

  ssh -Y login@hostname
- On the remote machine, set your display:

  export DISPLAY=192.168.1.1:0.0
  (this will be the machine that you are connecting *from*)
- Now start a program. Just run xeyes, or xcalc, or chrome, or whatever. The program should show up on your local X Window interface, after a while. It's running on the remote machine, but displaying locally.

Note that the remote machine doesn't even need to have an X Window server running on it. It's actually acting as the client, to your local computer's X Window server.

XDMCP is definitely "heavier" than a more optimized protocol for display changes, like VNC. Then again, the goal is different: VNC usually operates on the entire screen. And there's nothing to stop you from installing a VNC server, and going that route. In that case, any VNC client would work.

Comment: Ahh, ok that does help explain a bit. So my goal is to run the entire remote desktop though, and ideally in another TTY. So not launching a single remote program on my local X interface, but rather having the entire remote desktop (ideally in a new TTY, so I can switch easily), using both of my local monitors. Is this something I could do with VNC, for example?